# How do I manipulate and print a 2-D ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to make a program via GUI which accepts a student's first and last name, and four test marks. It should be able to output students' names and their marks, as well as calculate individual and class average.

I created a class Student and method updateStudentInfo

```
public class Student {
public String firstName;
public String lastName;
public ArrayList<Integer> courseMarks;


public void updateStudentInfo(String first, String last, int test1, int test2, int test3, int test4) {

    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;

    courseMarks = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    courseMarks.add(test1);
    courseMarks.add(test2);
    courseMarks.add(test3);
    courseMarks.add(test4);

}
```

Then the GUI:

```
public class StudentRecords extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>(); 


private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    Student s = new Student();
    s.updateStudentInfo(txtInputFirstName.getText(), txtInputLastName.getText(), new Integer(txtTest1.getText()),
    new Integer(txtTest2.getText()), new Integer(txtTest3.getText()), new Integer(txtTest4.getText()));
    studentList.add(s);

}
```

I don't completely understand the concept of using a class as a data type. But my main question is, how do I print the ArrayList, and calculate the averages?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Off-topic: Any reason for `public ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>(); ` later on while you are initializing it differently in your `Student` class? I prefer the later one. As you can add the `final` keyword there as well, making sure it is never replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with overriding the toString() method in your "Student" class. Once you do that, whenever you print an object of the Student class, it will print it out in a useful way as defined in the toString(). If you are using an IDE like eclipse or intelliJ, it can generate a toString() for you.
Here's a sample:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName
            + ", courseMarks=" + courseMarks + "]";
}
```

To calculate averages, you can add a method like this:

```
 float getAverage(){
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i: courseMarks){
        sum +=i;
    }
    return sum/courseMarks.size();              
}
```

and call it from your GUI as s.getAverage() to get the average marks for the student "s".

Comment: Be sure to cast sum to a float before return or youll fall victim to integer division. Alternately, declare sum a float.

Comment: Thanks! The toString() works well. How do I get multiple student names and marks to show up though? I tried running it through a for loop, but that doesn't seem to work..

Comment: @ChinmayeeGidwani Use a ListIterator.

Comment: @ChinmayeeGidwani or a for each.